# Given button color not showing but showing a color in colors file in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, colors

I am currently working on a project in android studio. In that app there are buttons in all activities. In the `MainActivity` (It is main menu of app) there are 3 buttons. I created a **drawable file** named **rounded**. It is used for the background of buttons. The following codes are in the `rounded` file. This will turn the buttons to round buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#9AFD36"
        android:centerColor="#8CE63E"
        android:endColor="@color/teal_700"
        android:angle="180"
        android:type="linear"/>
    <corners android:radius="10000dp"/>
</shape>
```

I added this background to buttons like this,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/areabtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Surface Area"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

In the 7th line I set background to that file and the buttons will show up that gradient there but when I run it, It turns to the **Primary Color** in the colors file. The following colors are in the colors file,(The primary color is `purple_500`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#11CC6B</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

This is in the code in `themes` file in the values folder.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MathematiciansCalculator" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also I have another gradient set to the back button in other activities but also they don't show the background given.
**Android Studio Version :- Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 11**

Comment: do you change the background color of those buttons anywhere in the code? not just xml layout

Comment: No I didn't do that. Also I created a new project and tried but the same happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you shared your **app theme** parent is Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

so Your button behave like, MaterialButton so please set backgroundTint as "**null**"

Answer (score 1):

**Use MaterialButton for round corners**

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_share"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorCard"
        android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:cornerRadius="28dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my question with the help of @KGeeks. As she told it needs `app:backgroundTint="@null"` line.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @RedDragon the point of the existing answers are good but not complete or solving your question properly in my opinion:

`app:backgroundTint="@null"` will disable the existing background color of the `MaterialButton` or change it if you put a value instead of `null`.

*Hint*: you can also use `app:background="@empty"`

But the important point to mention is that `MaterialButton` doesn't support gradients, only single colors.
A short field trip to why Tint instead of `android:background` from the documentation:

> Do not use the `android:background` attribute. `MaterialButton`
> manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background
> means `MaterialButton` can no longer guarantee that the new attributes
> it introduces will function properly. If the default background is
> changed, `MaterialButton` cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

---

As you can see that is very different from the standard widgets in Android, `MaterialDesign` is a library.

Now to the solutions of using gradients with a Button is following:

Make use of `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` if you are using Material Theme to be able to apply background gradients, because `MaterialButton` doesn't offer support to it yet as said before. There you can set your `drawable` as `android:background` attribute or with `@style`.

Answer (score 0):

use `app:backgroundTint="@color/buttonColor"` instead of `android:backgroundTint="@color/buttonColor"`